# MYSQL Join - Parent and Child table join and get only the latest record from the child table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables Posts and comments

**Post Table**

```
Post_id
Post_content
```

**Comments table**

```
comment_id
Comment
post_id
created_date
```

One post can have multiple comments or zero comments

My requirement is getting the latest comment for the posts using left outer join .

I mean result should be one record for the post with the below columns .

```
post_id,post_content ,comment_id,comment
```

In simple words posts should be getting along with their latest comment if it exists.

( Currently the system is getting the posts first and then going to the server again to get the latest comments to display , thought of getting them in one shot since we are displaying only one comment initially  ... Not sure what should be the best approach if wants to display more than one comment ..?)

Thank You

Regards

Kiran

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT Post.post_id, post_content, comment_id, comment
FROM
    Post LEFT JOIN Comments
        ON Post.post_id = Comments.post_id
        AND created_date = (
            SELECT MAX(created_date)
            FROM Comments
            WHERE Post.post_id = Comments.post_id
        )
```

BTW, you should consider indexing `Comments {post_id, created_date}` for optimal performance, but be mindful of the non-primary key index overhead in case you are using InnoDB (see the "Disadvantages of clustering" section in [this article](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/)).

Comment: Thanks for your response . I was thinking of similar to analytical functions in oracle . But couldn't find one in Mysql .

Comment: Thanks for the nice article too :) I was not knowing this .

Comment: @Bujji To my knowledge, there are no analytical functions a-la Oracle in MySQL. And you are welcome :)

Comment: Changed your query bit , instead on created_date , I am directly going against comment_id ... since comment Id max is definitely latest one for that post . Thanks again